# Child guard: canActivateChild not working

Tags: angular

I tried to put in place a child guard like the angular doc:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {

  constructor(private authService: AuthentificationService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    let url: string = state.url;

    return this.checkLogin(url);
  }

  canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    return this.canActivate(route, state);
  }

  checkLogin(url: string): boolean {
    /*****/
    return false;
  }
}
```

My routing.module:

```
import { AuthGuardService } from '../services/auth-guard.service';

const routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MyComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
        children: [{
            path: '',
            canActivateChild: [AuthGuardService],
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'candidature',
                    component: ListCandidatureComponent,
                },
                {
                    path: 'candidature/new',
                    component: NewCandidatureComponent
                }]
        }, {
            path: 'login',
            component: LoginComponent,

        }]
    }
]
```

I put my canActivateChild guard on the component-less part, to guard this routing by a authentification.

But with this configuration, when i tried to reach 'my.site.com/candidature' i've got this error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: guard is not a function ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: guard is not a function
```

Normally if i'm not authentitcated, i need to be redirected to the login page.
Does someone get this error or know why it's lunched?

Thank's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If find my solution. I explain for someone else who has the same problem.

Like excepted, the fact that the routing-module be a child routing module launch this error. I need to provide the AuthGuardService in de AppRouting to be used in a child-rounting-module like this:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    declarations: [],
    providers: [AuthGuardService] //Here add the AuthGuardService to be available in route-module-child
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 8):

The `canActivateChild: [AuthGuardService],` should not be inside `children`, but declared at the parent route.

Not really being sure, when you have declared children inside children of you need to declare the `canActivateChild` in the outer child as well. But you can test with and without it. Let me know if it works!

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MyComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
        canActivateChild: [AuthGuardService] // it should be placed here!
        children: [{
            path: '',
            // canActivateChild: [AuthGuardService], // needed or not?
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'candidature',
                    component: ListCandidatureComponent,
                },
                {
                    path: 'candidature/new',
                    component: NewCandidatureComponent
                }]
        }, {
            path: 'login',
            component: LoginComponent,

        }]
    }
]
```

Hope this helps!